# Finding node-disjoint routes with mutually exclusive nodes in graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I have the following problem. I would like to know if it reduces to some standard problem in Graph theory. Particularly, I would like to know whether it is NP-hard, if yes, how to prove its NP-hardness, if not, is there any algorithm that solves it.
Any suggestions are much appreciated.

In a undirected graph, I want to find the maximal number of node-disjoint routes from a source node to a destination node. Compared with the classical node-disjoint routing problem, I have a particular constraint here, i.e., we are given a number of sets, each containing a number of nodes in the graph, for any two node-disjoint routes we find, they cannot both contain nodes in the same node set. For example, if route R1 contains nodes in node set S1, then any other route cannot contain nodes in S1.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hypergraph matching can be reduced to this problem.  Let $\mathcal H$ be a hypergraph on vertex set $C$, thought of as a set of colours.  For each edge $E$ of $\mathcal H$, draw a path $P$ from the source to the destination such that the colours of the (internal) vertices of $P$ are precisely those in $E$.  Then paths from the source to the destination are in direct correspondence with edges of $\mathcal H$, and two paths have no colours in common if and only if the corresponding edges are disjoint.

Comment: Thank you Ben for your quick & nice response. Just a related question: if I modify my constraint and question as follows: now I want to calculate the max-flow of the graph (basically routes can share the same node), but still under the constraint of mutual exclusiveness given a number of node sets, as stated in my original question.

Comment: @user52871 Since edge-disjoint and vertex-disjoint paths from source to destination in the above example happen to coincide, hypergraph matching is also reducible to the max-flow problem.

Comment: Thanks again Ben. I just have another thought on your response to the original problem. It seems to me that according to your answer, the problem of finding maximal number of node-disjoint routes can also be cast into the hypergraph matching problem and is thus NP-hard. However, if I recall correctly, this problem is not NP-hard. In my opinion, it is the constraint on the node mutual exclusivity as stated in the problem that makes the problem NP-hard (it seems that you didn't use this constraint in your answer). Could you pls clarify this for me (or am I wrong anywhere)?

Comment: Another related question in case where the problem is NP-hard, could you point me some directions to look at to develop heuristic routing algorithms with good approximation? Thanks!

Comment: The extra constraint is essential.  In the reduction, every pair of paths from the source to the sink are vertex-disjoint, so the only restriction is that we must never use a colour more than once.  I'm afraid I don't know anything about approximation.

Comment: Thanks again. I see the point. In fact, the engineering problem behind is the routing problem in an adversal environment where some regions may be controlled by attackers. In such context, a natural way is to find multiple paths (as many as possible) and to avoid that any two paths are controlled by the same attacker.